# Problems calling child constructor using C# in XNA

Tags: c#, constructor, parent-child, xna-4.0

I have a two classes, and one inherits from the other.

---

**Partition**

```
class Partition
{
    protected Vector3 midpoint
    protected float radius
 
    public Partition(Vector3 midpoint, float radius)
    {    
        this.midpoint = midpoint;         
        this.radius = radius;
    }
}
```

---

**PartitionSegment**

```
class PartitionSegment : Partition
{
    protected Vector3 midpoint
    protected float radius
 
    public PartitionSegment(Vector3 midpoint, float radius)
    {    
        this.midpoint = midpoint;         
        this.radius = radius;
    }
}
```

---

I am being flagged for an error in PartitionSegment, for its constructor.

> **PartitionJunction**.PartitionJunction(**Vector3** midPoint, **float** radius)
>
> There is no argument given that corresponds to the required parameter 'midPoint' of 'Partition.Partition(Vector3, float)'

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You aren't calling the base class constructor.

Comment: Why does the child class duplicate the fields of the parent?

Comment: Either could be directly called to set up an element, and coordinates are required to determine position in the game world, for sorting.

Comment: _PartitionSegment_ is already inheriting _midpoint_ and _radius_ from _Partition_. You should have warnings telling you that those members are being hidden.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remembering my old days developing C#, don't you have to write ? :

```
public PartitionSegment(Vector3 midpoint, float radius) : base(midpoint, radius)
{ }
```

Comment: A simple solution. It appears my issue is an unfamiliarity with the base() function, but I think that's another question for another time.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the base constructor.

```
public PartitionSegment(Vector3 midpoint, float radius) : base(midpoint, radius)
{    
    //additional relevant code
}
```

Answer (score 1):

giving your partition base class a parameter less default constructor would also get rid of your error message.

Comment: It certainly would, but in this application, both need to handle the parameters.